# How to check if Browser is supported by <video> else show YouTube embedd

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I would like to have a Video on my Homepage. I want to use the  if the Browser is supported and if not I want to show a YouTube Embedd of that Video.

Hope yall can help!

Comment: Please add some code or describe what problems you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, 
you can use **Modernizr** to detect support for HTML5 video.

```
if (Modernizr.video) {
  // let's play some video!
} else {
  // no native video support available :(
  // maybe check for QuickTime or Flash instead
}
```

Comment: How do I implement the Video in there? Just throw in the HTML tags?